# Control multiple tables individually

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, toolbar

I'm using multiple html tables, each table has it own toolbar. But I'm not able to control each table individually. If you look at [the example](https://jsfiddle.net/84x7uhn3/), you can see that if I click the font-size button or line-height button, it affects both table.
I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to have unique ID's for each table.

i've tried working with:

```
closest('element-row').find('.title')
```

without any luck. Perhaps it's a possible solution, not sure.

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/84x7uhn3/)

```js
$(".line-height-btn").click(function() {
  if ($(".large-line-height").length) {
    $("td").removeClass("large-line-height").addClass("medium-line-height");
  } else if ($(".medium-line-height").length) {
    $("td").removeClass("medium-line-height").addClass("small-line-height");
  } else if ($(".small-line-height").length) {
    $("td").removeClass("small-line-height").addClass("large-line-height");
  } else {
    $("td").addClass("medium-line-height");
  }
});

$(".format-size-btn").click(function() {
  if ($(".large-font-size").length) {
    $("td").removeClass("large-font-size").addClass("medium-font-size");
  } else if ($(".medium-font-size").length) {
    $("td").removeClass("medium-font-size").addClass("small-font-size");
  } else if ($(".small-font-size").length) {
    $("td").removeClass("small-font-size").addClass("large-font-size");
  } else {
    $("td").addClass("medium-font-size");
    console.log("Hello world!");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.large-line-height {
  line-height: 3rem !important;
}

.medium-line-height {
  line-height: 2rem !important;
}

.small-line-height {
  line-height: 1rem !important;
}

.large-font-size {
  font-size: 16px !important;
  letter-spacing: -0.004em !important;
}

.medium-font-size {
  font-size: 14px !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.001em !important;
}

.small-font-size {
  font-size: 12px !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.008em !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="table-card">
  <div class="table-title-row">
    <div class="table-title-text">
      <h3>Header</h3></div>
    <div class="table-title-buttons">
      <a class="btn format-size-btn">
        <i class="material-icons">
          format_size
        </i>
        <span class="btn-label"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="btn line-height-btn">
        <i class="material-icons">
          line_weight
        </i>
        <span class="btn-label"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-container">
    <table class="custom-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="check-all" type="checkbox">
              <label for="check-all"></label>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th align="right">Object</th>
          <th align="left">Type</th>
          <th align="left">Group</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="check-1" type="checkbox">
              <label for="check-1"></label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="right">123</td>
          <td align="left">ABC</td>
          <td align="left">Family</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="check-2" type="checkbox">
              <label for="check-2"></label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="right">123</td>
          <td align="left">ABC</td>
          <td align="left">Family</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="check-3" type="checkbox">
              <label for="check-3"></label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="right">123</td>
          <td align="left">ABC</td>
          <td align="left">Family</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="table-card">
  <div class="table-title-row">
    <div class="table-title-text">
      <h3>Header</h3></div>
    <div class="table-title-buttons">
      <a class="btn format-size-btn">
        <i class="material-icons">
          format_size
        </i>
        <span class="btn-label"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="btn line-height-btn">
        <i class="material-icons">
          line_weight
        </i>
        <span class="btn-label"></span>
      </a>
   
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-container">
    <table class="custom-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="check-all" type="checkbox">
              <label for="check-all"></label>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th align="right">Object</th>
          <th align="left">Type</th>
          <th align="left">Group</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="check-1" type="checkbox">
              <label for="check-1"></label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="right">123</td>
          <td align="left">ABC</td>
          <td align="left">Family</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="check-2" type="checkbox">
              <label for="check-2"></label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="right">123</td>
          <td align="left">ABC</td>
          <td align="left">Family</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="check-3" type="checkbox">
              <label for="check-3"></label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="right">123</td>
          <td align="left">ABC</td>
          <td align="left">Family</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("td")` is a global selector.  It will find **all** tds in the document.

Comment: Please post your HTML, as most will not bother with clicking a link to view an image.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code **in the question itself** not only on a third-party site.

Comment: `closest('element-row')` is also an invalid selector.  If you meant it to find a class, you are missing the `.` on the selector.

Comment: Why don't you pick an answer? Is your question not answered yet?

Answer (score 0):

`let $td = $(evt.target).closest('.table-title-row').next('.table-container').find('td');` inside your handler function will - given your current HTML structure - find the table cells you want.

```js
$(".line-height-btn").on("click", function(evt) {
  let $tbody = $(evt.target).closest('.table-title-row').next('.table-container').find('tbody')[0];
  switch($tbody.className) {
  case "large-line-height":
    $tbody.className = "medium-line-height";
    break;
  case "medium-line-height":
    $tbody.className = "small-line-height";
    break;
  case "small-line-height":
    $tbody.className = "large-line-height";
    break;
  default:
    $tbody.className = "medium-line-height";
  }
});

$(".format-size-btn").on("click", function(evt) {
  let $table = $(evt.target).closest('.table-title-row').next('.table-container').find('table')[0];
  switch($table.className) {
  case "large-font-size":
    $table.className = "medium-font-size";
    break;
  case "medium-font-size":
    $table.className = "small-font-size";
    break;
  case "small-font-size":
    $table.className = "large-font-size";
    break;
  default:
    $table.className = "medium-font-size";
    console.log("Hello world!");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.large-line-height td {
  line-height: 3rem !important;
}

.medium-line-height td  {
  line-height: 2rem !important;
}

.small-line-height td  {
  line-height: 1rem !important;
}

.large-font-size td  {
  font-size: 16px !important;
  letter-spacing: -0.004em !important;
}

.medium-font-size td  {
  font-size: 14px !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.001em !important;
}

.small-font-size td  {
  font-size: 12px !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.008em !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="table-card">
  <div class="table-title-row">
    <div class="table-title-text">
      <h3>Header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="table-title-buttons">
      <a class="btn format-size-btn">
        <i class="material-icons">
          format_size
        </i>
        <span class="btn-label"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="btn line-height-btn">
        <i class="material-icons">
          line_weight
        </i>
        <span class="btn-label"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="check-all" type="checkbox">
              <label for="check-all"></label>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th align="right">Object</th>
          <th align="left">Type</th>
          <th align="left">Group</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="check-1" type="checkbox">
              <label for="check-1"></label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="right">123</td>
          <td align="left">ABC</td>
          <td align="left">Family</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="check-2" type="checkbox">
              <label for="check-2"></label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="right">123</td>
          <td align="left">ABC</td>
          <td align="left">Family</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="check-3" type="checkbox">
              <label for="check-3"></label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="right">123</td>
          <td align="left">ABC</td>
          <td align="left">Family</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="table-card">
  <div class="table-title-row">
    <div class="table-title-text">
      <h3>Header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="table-title-buttons">
      <a class="btn format-size-btn">
        <i class="material-icons">
          format_size
        </i>
        <span class="btn-label"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="btn line-height-btn">
        <i class="material-icons">
          line_weight
        </i>
        <span class="btn-label"></span>
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="check-all" type="checkbox">
              <label for="check-all"></label>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th align="right">Object</th>
          <th align="left">Type</th>
          <th align="left">Group</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="check-1" type="checkbox">
              <label for="check-1"></label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="right">123</td>
          <td align="left">ABC</td>
          <td align="left">Family</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="check-2" type="checkbox">
              <label for="check-2"></label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="right">123</td>
          <td align="left">ABC</td>
          <td align="left">Family</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="check-3" type="checkbox">
              <label for="check-3"></label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td align="right">123</td>
          <td align="left">ABC</td>
          <td align="left">Family</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to be working, almost every time. But if I jump between the toolbars, clicks the button fairly random the button inside the table i'm currently not clicking stops working. I'm able to make it clickable again by matching the same font-size in both tables. As if it's depending on  each other.

Comment: The reason for that is that again you check if there's *any*  td with those classes you check for. That will also match the other table's tds. Changed the concept a little and adjusted the code.

Comment: This one works! however, how would you scale this if there's additional buttons inside the toolbar, perhaps adding contrast colors or what ever?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$(".line-height-btn").click(function() {
if ($(".large-line-height").length) {
$(this).parent().parent().next().find("td").removeClass("large-line-height").addClass("medium-line-height");
} else if ($(".medium-line-height").length) {
 $(this).parent().parent().next().find("td").removeClass("medium-line-height").addClass("small-line-height");
} else if ($(".small-line-height").length) {
 $(this).parent().parent().next().find("td").removeClass("small-line-height").addClass("large-line-height");
  } else {
    $(this).parent().parent().next().find("td").addClass("medium-line-height");
     }
    });
```

Similarly apply this kind of logic for $(".format-size-btn").click()

Comment: It seems as if I'm only able to control the table I start interacting with. If click the second tables button, I'm not be able to control the first table unless i reset the second table, then I'm able to control only the first.